# set image using default for particular store view by code

Tags: magento-1.9, product, multistore, product-images, magmi

Is there any method to set all image(thumb, small, base) using default value for particular store view.

I got strange problem, I installed 2 languages magento, and one day all image in one store view just missing. so I checked on product detail admin, I found that all images are still there. However all images on one store view set as no image. I have 1000+ SKU. how can I mass update all product using default store value ?

I'm trying to search magmi function, and it doesn't provide update for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`store`](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Magmi_Behaviour_-_store_column) column in Magmi, which takes the Magento store view code, so use default.

And you can prefix the image source with a + sign to set it as default, e.g.

```
    store                                          image
   default               +http://foo.com/media/catalog/product/s/f/sfv9007a_front.jpg
```

Include the same for `small_image` and `thumbnail` attributes in CSV file above and it should work.

Also make sure you have the *Image Attributes Processor* plugin enabled within Magmi.

Comment: So i just set store column to specific store and put all image column value = + , correct ?

Comment: Oh i need to find image source first ?

Comment: Export the products that don't have image set first.

Comment: Thk so much!!! I will try now

Comment: I think I misunderstand, my problem is only one store view image is set to "no image". so ur method I need to set store="store problem" and image=+image parth. am i correct ?

Comment: Yes, but make sure you have enabled **Image Attributes Processor** in Magmi

Comment: it works !!!! thks :)

Comment: @Adrift:  My Multi Store : https://snag.gy/rGlAPY.jpg, i need to import images for my store : english. my csv screen shots : https://snag.gy/Q9ZEme.jpg. its not working. What is the error?